# "Isolating" drawing of child windows / sub-elements in Win32 API (GDI)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, graphics, gdi

I'm attempting to make a GUI layout that looks something like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+         +                 +       +
+         +                 +   3   +
+         +                 +       +
+    1    +        2        +++++++++
+         +                 +       +
+         +                 +   4   +
+         +                 +       +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

All of these areas/elements will be fully custom drawn, and I have already written most of the painting functions for these 4 individual elements.

Initially, I had a child window that was merely an implementation of (2) above, that simply occupied the entire main window.

Then I decided to do a bit of an overhaul when I realized (whoa!) that I could just do all the custom drawing directly in the main window instead of in a child window.

I have recently begun implementing drawing (3) and (4), and currently draw everything using the same window/procedure (`WM_PAINT` handler). I have one memory DC (for double-buffering) and one bitmap for the entire client area that I draw with/to. In the process of implementing these 2 elements, one thing I've been a bit peeved about, especially since I draw everything onto a single window/bitmap, is that I always need to add the respective offsets for the start of each element's rectangle each time I want to paint a inside of one particular element (+ strictly ensure the drawn contents won't crash/overlap with the other elements), rather than using plain offsets relative to the elements themselves.

For instance, (2) contains a waveform that's drawn using `Polyline`, and does something like `PolylinePoints[N].x = waveformRectangle->x + sample_x_coord` instead of simply `PolylinePoints[N].x = sample_x_coord`. And mind you, this is in a loop of often 1000+ iterations, so it adds up to a lot of instructions.

Would it be ill-advised to allocate 3 more DCs and/or bitmaps only to "isolate" the drawing into 4 different contexts? Or is there an even better way to accomplish what I want without so many resources? Is it crazy altogether to draw this kind of UI using only one window/process? Or would it mostly be a waste of time to make an overhaul to use child windows once again? Keep in mind that I also intend to draw (3) and (4) as one single element (i.e. "combined") in some cases.

Appreciate any tips or best practice advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am blind so can't see exactly what you hope to accomplish but why not change the coordinate frame with SetViewportOrgEx/SetViewportExtEx for each part of the window (that is, changing where 0, 0 lands)? That way you can use coordinates that are more convenient for a particular sub-region of the window without going through the trouble of creating memory DCs and blitting back into the main DC.

Comment: That's precisely the solution to the problem. [Coordinate Spaces and Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/coordinate-spaces-and-transformations) has more information on the topic.

Comment: @IInspectable @SoronelHaetir  Yep, I believe this is definitely a step in the right direction. `SetViewportOrgEx` works great, and as expected. However, I think I'm failing to see the use of `SetViewportExtEx` specifically. I thought that function would essentially define a clipping rectangle to avoid painting outside of a particular area ("extent"), but when I tested it just now with a quick `DrawText` call, I'm still able to paint over elements outside of the set extent. MSDN doesn't give me any additional clues to be honest. Could someone try to clarify it briefly?

Comment: Those functions simply translate coordinates from one coordinate space into another coordinate space. See [clipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/clipping) if you need your drawing to be clipped to a rectangle or region.

Comment: Alright then, I think I'm satisfied. Thanks guys.